# Who unscheduled my jobs

Tags: scheduled-job

I have some scheduled jobs running in production, they stopped and I don't find the cause.
I am looking for the reason, but I don't find any trace.

Is there any way to know the cause?
Maybe someone stopped them for a good reason, but I don't find the way to know who or why.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, but did you check the Setup Audit Log? Not sure if scheduling changes are included, but maybe you're lucky.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but I didn't find anything